# CDO.message crashing excel

Tags: excel, vba, gmail, cdo.message

I've been running this code for a long time, even earlier today. However, whenever I try to run it now (with no changes) it crashes Excel when the code reaches "Set NewMail = New CDO.message". Is there a reason why?

[image]

Comment: Define 'crash'... is there any error message given?  My first thought is to reboot the machine.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.. I believe the Excel program updated without my knowledge and the code previously used was no longer compatible. I specifically created the object instead.

[Updated Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8IbD.png)